# Cognito Form source code appearing on Blogspot

Tags: blogger, cognito-forms

Cognito provided this code to embed on my Blogspot webpage:

```
<div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/include/required"></script>
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/session/script/24360497-2969-4b17-be64-98a270f99885"></script>
<script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "1" });</script>
</div>
```

However on the page it appears as the hyperlink:

```
Cognito.load("forms", { id: "1" })
```

Can I rename this? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: I am a developer with Cognito Forms. When you added your form to your blog did you add the embed code under the "Compose" or "HTML" option?

Comment: I embedded code in the HTML option... thanks!!

Comment: In testing I was able to add embed code to the HTML option, by doing this the form displayed correctly. If your from is still not displaying correctly the issue might not be how the form is embedded. In order to look into this further could you submit a support ticket(https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport)?

Answer (score -2):

I'm posting it in PageLime.

The code is this. I'm changing the address to XX.

```
<div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/XXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "1" });</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.